# NGINX and CGit configuration

Tags: nginx, cgi, gitolite

I?m trying to setup CGit and NGINX. I'm almost there but I have a problem with the rewrite rule in my NGINX's conf file.

Currently I have this:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  cgit.mydomain.com;
    index cgit.cgi;
    gzip off;

    root /usr/share/webapps/cgit;

    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/cgit.cgi;

    location / {
        try_files $uri @cgit;
    }

    location @cgit {
        auth_basic "Restricted";
        auth_basic_user_file /path/to/my/password_file;

        gzip off;
        rewrite ^/([^/]+/.*)?$ /cgit.cgi?url=$1 break;
        fastcgi_pass    fcgiwrap;
    }
}
```

I understand that the URL when I'm looking at `demo_repo_1.git` should look like `http://cgit.mydomain.com/cgit.cgi?url=gitolite-admin.git` (or something similar?) but instead it looks like `http://cgit.mydomain.com/cgit.cgi/gitolite-admin.git/`, and it doesn't work (as in `cgit.cgi` script can't read the correct data from the URL and can't show the right information about my repos.

Also, if I force the URL that I think it should be (copy&paste the "right" URL in my browser) the `cgit.cgi` script gets downloaded.

Can I get some help with that rewrite rule, please?